# Biased initial dataset active learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Does selecting a biased initial(seed) dataset effect the training and accuracy of the machine built using active learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may. Suppose a seed data sample is heavily biased and model has not seen any examples of a particular cluster. Then while predicting, the model may predict them as belonging to some other class and do this with high certainty (i.e. it has gotten heavily biased). And so it wouldn't feel the need to query labels for such data instances and won't learn them. But when we later test model's results with true labels, it will show low accuracy because these were actually wrong predictions.

Having said that, we also may not desire a 'perfectly uniform' distribution of training data in seed dataset, since if we have a considerable number of outliers or incorrect label by human error or heavily skewed but less probable data cluster which can be undesired, it would hamper the model.

One solution can be 'active cleaning' of such instances, or otherwise, we can allow seed data to have some amount of intentional bias (which can be towards high-density clusters or influential labels or ensemble disagreements or uncertainty of model). We then make sure to account for this introduced bias in the model in our further decision-making process based on the model's results.